# If I join a prop trading firm, will I enjoy low commissions

Tags: canada, trading, ontario, commission

I often hear that professional traders pay negligible (<1 cent ) commission per trade. Is this true?

Does this mean that if I open up an account with a prop trading firm in Toronto and put up 25k, I get to enjoy the high leverage and also pay next to nothing in commissions?

Comment: Please note: professional traders pay less than one cent PER SHARE TRADED, not per trade.  There is a big difference.  When I managed money professionally we spent plenty on commissions.  For large pots of money, trading at $7 a trade like scottrade allows is a lot less than what they pay.  Though they probably get better execution as well, so the two are not comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prop (proprietary) traders trade using huge amounts of a bank's money (i.e. other people's money) so the reason why they have such low commissions (and they certainly do) is that the firms for which they work negotiate low commissions as the quantities and volumes (as they also trade very frequently) will be high and so the total commission will be very high. There is no such thing as a prop trading account unless you are a big bank with a very large bank roll (tens of millions of USD) so you cannot open one to enjoy those benefits unless you have enough money that you can negotiate your commission with brokers. 25k CAD is definitely not enough money to even start a conversation about those sorts of commissions.

note: prop traders are generally banned from trading intraday with their own money by their employers and the law as it is a massive conflict of interests. Those who do and get caught face lengthy prison sentences.